# jstl validation error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, validation, jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${codeList}" var="code">                                                               
    <option value="${code.dtlCd }" <c:if test="${guide.seminarType eq 
    code.dtlCd}">selected="selected"</c:if>>${code.dtlNm }</option>
</c:forEach>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with `EL Expression` instead

```
<c:forEach items="${codeList}" var="code">                                                               
    <option value="${code.dtlCd }" ${guide.seminarType eq code.dtlCd ? 'selected':''}>
    ${code.dtlNm }
    </option>
</c:forEach>
```